# The sum of uncountable things and countable things

Tags: countability

There are red colour, yellow colour and three pencils. Could I say “there are five things (2 qualities + 3 objects)”?

Comment: I assume you mean that there are three pencils, either 2 red, 1 yellow or 1 red, 2 yellow.  I can't imagine any language where this would be called "5"

Comment: This sounds like a philosophical question, not an ELL question.

Comment: @James K Are you mad? I’m sorry..